# How to find data inside array that is most closest to a condition

Tags: c#, arrays, closest

I have an array of double `Double[] array = new Double[5];`

For example, if the array contains data like this:

> {0.5 , 1.5 , 1.1 , 0.6 , 2}

How do I find the number that is closest to 1? The output should be `1.1`, because it's the one that is closest to 1 in this case.

Comment: Do you want the number (1.1) or the position (2) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var result = source.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(1 - x)).First();
```

Requires `using System.Linq;` at the top of a file. It's *O(n log(n))* solution.

**Update**

If you're really afraid about performance and want *O(n)* solution, you can use [`MinBy()` extension method from ***moreLINQ*** library](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs?r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c).

Or you could use `Aggregate()` method:

```
var result = source.Aggregate(
                new { val = 0d, abs = double.MaxValue },
                (a, i) => Math.Abs(1 - i) > a.abs ? a : new { val = i, abs = Math.Abs(1 - i) },
                a => a.val);
```

Comment: But sorting seems overly expensive.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It's *O(n*log(n))* solution. I know *O(n)* is possible, but I would not be afraid about that unless array has thousands elements.

Comment: Yes, I knew there was something like MinBy(). Can probably expand on that to get the index if needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this in a simple way using LINQ:

```
var closestTo1 = array.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x - 1)).First();
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should be easy to understand by any programmer and has O(n) complexity (non-LINQ):

```
double minValue = array[0];
double minDifference = Math.Abs(array[0] - 1);

foreach (double val in array)
{
    int dif = Math.Abs(x - 1);   

    if (dif < minValue) 
    {
        minDifference = dif;
        minValue = val;
    }
}
```

After this code executes, `minValue` will have your required value.

**Code summary:**

It will set the minimum value as the first element of the array. Then the difference will be the absolute value of the first element minus 1.

This loop will linear search the array and find the minimum value of the array. If the difference is less than the minimum value it will set a new minimum difference and minimum value.

Comment: Yes, but very old-school. Good when performance is most important.

Comment: My guess is that LINQ has better performance. Generally I prefer most non-LINQ solutions because it's easier to understand for beginners and I only learned about LINQ based on my previous questions.